# Dismiss snackbar immediately

Tags: android, android-design-library, floating-action-button, android-snackbar

I am using `FloatingActionButton`, `Snackbar` and `CoordinatorLayout` to make room for snackbar when it is shown.

Now when the contextual mode is called on the listview I call `snackbar.dismiss()`. If I set the `FloatingActionButton` to invisible and snackbar is still shown, the `FloatingActionButton` is displaced by 'CoordinatorLayout' but it remains there even after it is made visible.

Is there any way for `Snackbar` to be dismissed without animation, immediately, so that the displacement can't happen in the first place?

Comment: have a look over it  -->https://lab.getbase.com/introduction-to-coordinator-layout-on-android/

Comment: This is an introduction to coordinator layout. Custom CoordinatorLayout can be made, but it would not be that reliable as the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this issue has been fixed from `Design library 23.3.0` onwards.